# How can I best plot timestamps by frequency-to-date?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

I have a site called Sudomemo. I record when I first see a user in the database; and I've exported it in JSON format, located here.

http://www.sudomemo.net/statistics/firstSeenDump.php

I've done this:

```
dates = Import["http://www.sudomemo.net/statistics/firstSeenDump.php", "JSON"]
```

I want to plot, since February, how the user-join rate increases/decreases, over the course of the year.

Thinking about it mathematically: Since the derivative of a function shows the slope of a function, and the second derivative shows the concavity/how quickly the slope is changing, I should graph the second derivative of the timestamps over the year. I *think* I have the right idea... I'm still learning about derivatives in Calculus :P

The only issue is, I have no idea how to go about doing that!

I'm pretty new to Mathematica, and thought this would make a fantastic chart. Not only that, but I've installed Mathematica 10 on my server, and I'd love to be able to present <s>cool graphs :D</s> some interesting statistics to interested users.

Right now, I've simply used the `json_encode()` PHP function to produce the timestamps like this:

```
["2014-01-29 16:49:00","2014-01-29 16:49:00","2014-01-29 16:49:00"...
```

I can change the array format to something different if that'd be better suited for this.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

*Note: The first hundred values or so are all 2014-01-29 16:49:00 because that's when I first started recording the "first seen" timestamps.*

*http://www.sudomemo.net/statistics/firstSeenDump.php?nospike doesn't show the ones from January 29th 16:49:00.*

Comment: You can cast to `DateObject` like this: `Map[StringSplit[#, {" ", ":", "-"}] & /* Map[ToExpression] /* DateObject]`

Answer (score 5):

You're about to realize that derivatives in the real world are a pain. You have to aggregate data as much as possible and average it a lot until you get a "textbook-quality second-derivative!

```
dates = DateList /@ Import["http://www.sudomemo.net/statistics/firstSeenDump.php", "JSON"]
```

Grouping by days and counting:

```
datesDays = Tally@dates[[All, ;; 3]]; 
datesDays // DateListPlot
```

> [image: By days]

Very noisy, as every real world data... and when we differentiate noise we make it stronger.

```
MapThread[{#1[[1]], (#2[[2]] - #1[[2]])/DayCount[#1[[1]], #2[[1]]]} &
    , {Most@#, Drop[#, 1]}] &@dayCounts // DateListPlot
```

> [image: first derivative]

We'd get a similar plot if we differentiated it once more.

#### Some MovingAverage filtering

```
datesWeeks = Thread[{datesDays[[;; -7, 1]], MovingAverage[datesDays[[All, 2]], 7]}];
datesMonths = Thread[{datesDays[[;; -30, 1]], MovingAverage[datesDays[[All, 2]], 30]}];
GraphicsGrid@{DateListPlot /@ {%%, %}}
```

> [image: Weeks and Months Average]

But even the well-behaved 30-day-average data becomes too noisy under a single differentiation:

```
MapThread[{#1[[1]], (#2[[2]] - #1[[2]])/DayCount[#1[[1]], #2[[1]]]} & , {Most@#, Drop[#, 1]}] &@datesMonths // DateListPlot[#, PlotRange -> All] &
```

> [image: Differentiated Month]

You could average the result before taking another derivative, but remember that every averaging step adds more lag to your system... Old data is just as actionable as noisy data!

#### Just for kicks, second derivative, with and without averaging

Using the same "methodology" as before:

```
diffMonthAvg = Thread[{diffMonth[[;; -30, 1]], MovingAverage[diffMonth[[All, 2]], 30]}];

MapThread[{#1[[1]], (#2[[2]] - #1[[2]])/DayCount[#1[[1]], #2[[1]]]} &, {Most@#, Drop[#, 1]}] &@diffMonth;
MapThread[{#1[[1]], (#2[[2]] - #1[[2]])/DayCount[#1[[1]], #2[[1]]]} &, {Most@#, Drop[#, 1]}] &@diffMonthAvg;
GraphicsGrid@{DateListPlot[#, PlotRange -> {All, {-3, 3}}] & /@ {%%, %}}
```

[image: Second derivative]

You can also apply the moving average to the second derivative, but it's late and we all know that squinting hard achieves the same result!

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! :D
These are both neat, I'm going to give some of these a try! :D Thanks! (Not sure which answer to accept but I want to accept one eventually)!

Answer (score 5):

You have the import.

```
dates = Import["http://www.sudomemo.net/statistics/firstSeenDump.php", "JSON"]
```

Gather them up by day and count how many in each day.

```
dailyGather = GatherBy[dates, Take[DateList[#], 3] &];
dailyVisits = {Take[DateList[dailyGather[[#, 1]]], 3],Length[dailyGather[[#]]]} & 
 /@ Range[First@Dimensions[dailyGather]];
```

Plot the visits.

```
DateListPlot[dailyVisits, PlotRange -> All]
```

Calc and plot the pace of visits.

```
paceOfVisits = MovingMap[#[[2]] - #[[1]] &, dailyVisits, 2];
DateListPlot[paceOfVisits, PlotRange -> All]
```

Calc and plot the change in pace of visits.

```
changeOfPaceOfVisits = MovingMap[#[[2]] - #[[1]] &, paceOfVisits, 2];
DateListPlot[changeOfPaceOfVisits, PlotRange -> All]
```

Look at smoothing the change in pace with average.

```
Manipulate[
 DateListPlot[MovingAverage[changeOfPaceOfVisits, averageN], 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-100, 100}}], {averageN, 3, 25, 1}]
```

## **Update**

You can try more smoothers with `MovingMap` instead of `MovingAverage` in the `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[
 DateListPlot[MovingMap[smoother, changeOfPaceOfVisits, averageN], 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-100, 100}}], 
 {smoother, {Mean, Median, Quantile[#, .8] & -> "80% Quantile", 
   TrimmedMean[#, .1] & -> "10% Trimmed Mean"}, SetterBar}, 
 {averageN, 3, 30, 1}]
```

Comment: `MovingMap`! That exists!

Comment: @Aisamu Yes, In version 10.

Comment: It even does some nice `DateList` conversion automagically! (`#[[2]]-#[[1]]` evaluates to `3600633600`, instead of `{0, 1, -23}` on the first term of paceOfVisits)

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! :D
These are both neat, I'm going to give some of these a try! :D Thanks! (Not sure which answer to accept but I want to accept one eventually)!

Comment: @Aisamu Try more smoothers with `MovingMap'.  See the update.